# Recreating secure token functionality from C# into Java

Tags: java, c#, base64, sha256

I have an application I am converting from C# to Java (eventually I want to make this an android app).

To give some background: the application connects to a web server, with a JSON formatted request for a 'key' to log in. Within the JSON is a token which is generated by the following code:

```
public static string GenToken(string secret, string str)
    {
        string token;
        using (var stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(str)))
        {

            using (var hmac = new System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA256(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(secret)))
            {
                var hash = hmac.ComputeHash(stream);        
                var hashStr = BitConverter.ToString(hash);        
                token = string.Format("{0}.{1}", hashStr.Replace("-", ""), str);

            }
        }

        return Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(token));
    }
```

The closest I have found is some code I found [here](https://www.jokecamp.com/blog/examples-of-creating-base64-hashes-using-hmac-sha256-in-different-languages/#java) but this is still not producing the same result as the C# code.

What I need is something that will produce the same result in Java as this bit of c# code. Otherwise the authentication fails.

For reference, I am testing using the values:

```
secret = 7353388933d07b2a1ef462c9d3f4e8ca;
str = {"userId":"bcf4fc83-291a-11e7-9def-06948e004f29","expires":1516015203090}
```

This outputs

```
OTQyMDk1NTI2Mzc3NDYyRjk1RTYzQzUzNUVCNzg3MDQ1NjlBNDQ5OEM1MTM1N0I2QTQ3REY1OTA5M0Q3MjMzQS57InVzZXJJZCI6ImJjZjRmYzgzLTI5MWEtMTFlNy05ZGVmLTA2OTQ4ZTAwNGYyOSIsImV4cGlyZXMiOjE1MTYwMTUyMDMwOTB9
```

**EDIT**
I have gotten as far as realising that

```
using (var stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(str)))
```

Is producing a hex value of

```
 7B-22-75-73-65-72-49-64-22-3A-22-62-63-66-34-66-63-38-33-2D-32-39-31-61-2D-31-31-65-37-2D-39-64-65-66-2D-30-36-39-34-38-65-30-30-34-66-32-39-22-2C-22-65-78-70-69-72-65-73-22-3A-31-35-31-36-30-31-35-32-30-33-30-39-30-7D
```

Which I have been able to do with the following in Java (removing the need to replace the dashes)

```
public static String toHex(String arg) {
    return String.format("%040X", new BigInteger(1, arg.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)));
}
```

But I'm well and truly stuck after this point.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The C# code:

1. converts the hash to its hexadecimal representation `hashStr`. To convert a byte array to a hexadecimal string in Java see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9655181/368220) post.
2. removes "-" that were introduced by BitConverter. You won't need to do this in Java, since adding "-" is specific to BitConverter.
3. concatenates `hashStr` and `str` with a dot in between to get a `token`. This is trivial in Java: `token = hashStr + "." + str`.
4. converts the token to a base64 encoding. To do this in Java, use `Base64.encodeBase64String` as was done in your [example](https://www.jokecamp.com/blog/examples-of-creating-base64-hashes-using-hmac-sha256-in-different-languages/#java)

The code you're [referring](https://www.jokecamp.com/blog/examples-of-creating-base64-hashes-using-hmac-sha256-in-different-languages/#java) to does not perform these steps. Did you consider adding these steps to the Java code?

Comment: Edit: Thanks Martijin, new to stackoverflow and getting used to what you can/can't do in comments. Not thinking straight today being full of flu! I'll edit original post.